# Cannot console login after updating nVidia driver

Tags: nvidia, 18.04

I just updated my nvidia driver on a recent ubuntu installation, and this broke my system like it did to many others.

However, differently from the others it seems, my system has broken so much I can't even console login.

On startup, the screen is first black, then shows some text for a second or so (below), then it becomes black again for three seconds. If I press e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> when the text is shown, the console login screen replaces the text, and it is shown alternatingly with the black screen for such a small time that I cannot possibly use that to login.

Any suggestions on how to get out of it without having to completely reinstall my system?

Many thanks!
[image]

Comment: After Ctrl-Alt-F3, what happens if you try logging in blind?

Comment: @unutbu the command line is only responsive when the console login is showing, a second or less every 4-5. It's very hard to login by typing only 2 characters of my username and password every time and I haven't managed that yet.

Comment: I have a bootable USB that I could use to potentially changing system files in my system. Any idea if that could work somehow? It seems that you could solve this by changing your xorg.conf, but I don't seem to have a xorg.conf file.

Comment: If the machine accepts remote logins and you have access to another machine, perhaps you could use telnet or ssh to log in to the broken machine and repair it remotely.

Comment: I cannot login remotely unfortunately, but I could do as above

Comment: Just to be certain -- is the console problem the same for all the consoles `Ctrl-Alt-F1` through `Ctrl-Alt-F6`)?

Comment: yes it is, it doesn't matter which shell I use

Comment: You may be able to boot from the USB, then [use chroot](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCdRecovery) so that you can run commands as though you had booted your machine.

Comment: [This guy](https://askubuntu.com/q/1097971/8005) managed to install NVIDIA drivers from the live USB; it should be possible to remove them as well.

Comment: More information on using chroot [here](https://superuser.com/q/111152/14566). Includes instructions on repairing `/etc/resolv.conf`.

Comment: that seems like a good idea, but after spending several hours on this I got fed up and am just reinstalling the whole system from scratch

Comment: With good backups, the option of reinstalling is a blessing.